# Variable for lower TF on pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I am tring to write variables for lower TF. I wrote this but i get an error.
I don't have this problem when it is for higher TF.

```
I = timeframe.multiplier
var resLTF = timeframe.ismonthly ? I >= 12 ? '3M' : I >= 3 ? '1M' : I >= 1 ? 'W' : timeframe.isweekly ? 'D' : timeframe.isdaily ? I >= 2 ? '480' : I >= 1 ? '240' : timeframe.isintraday ? I >= 480 ? '120' : I >= 240 ? '60' : I >= 120 ? '30' : I >= 60 ? '15' : I >= 30 ? '5' : I >= 15 ? '3' : I >= 10 ? '2' : I >= 2 ? '10'
```

I have this error..

```
Mismatched input end of line without line continuation expecting ':'
```

I checked the spaces, but everything looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last mentioned variable is stated ? Which is the ternary equivalent of “if”. You need to end with : and a condition which is “else”. Even if it’s just : na, you need something.

Cheers!